# C# WPF dynamic names for input

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic

So I'm trying to add dynamically inputs and retreive date from them and only do an action when a user presses enter in the input. So, what I'm currently doing is appending the inputs to a stacklayout. which works fine. Also the naming works. I use the following function;

```
private void GenerateGTKInputs()
{
    // Based on the settings for the tour
    // we generate the correct inputs in the stacklayout given in the XAML

    // First: clear all the children
    stackpanel_gtk.Children.Clear();

    if (inp_team_number.Text != "")
    {
        // get the data for the part and the class etc...
        var data_gtk = tour_settings[(Convert.ToInt32(inp_team_number.Text.Substring(0, 1)) - 1)].tour_data[inp_tour_part.SelectedIndex].gtks;

        // Now: Make the layout
        foreach (var item in data_gtk)
        {
            // Stack panel (main 'div')
            StackPanel main_stack_panel = new StackPanel()
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
            };

            // Text blok with the name of the GTK
            TextBlock gtk_name = new TextBlock()
            {
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                Text = "GTK " + item.gtk
            };

            // Input field
            Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox input = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox()
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(15, 0, 0, 0),
                Width = 40,
                Height = Double.NaN, // Automatic height
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                Mask = "00:00",
                Name = "gtk_" + item.gtk
            };

            // Add to the main stack panel
            main_stack_panel.Children.Add(gtk_name);
            main_stack_panel.Children.Add(input);

            // Append to the main main frame
            stackpanel_gtk.Children.Add(main_stack_panel);
        }
    }
}
```

Now as you can see, I'm giving them a name, but I have no clue what so ever on how to "bind" an trigger event (`KeyDown`) with a check on enter button press with dynamic names. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "bind" a trigger event by adding to the appropriate event of the control - in this case you need to create a method like :

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
{
    // Get reference to the input control that fired the event
    Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox input = (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox)sender;
    // input.Name can now be used
}
```

and add this to the KeyDown event :

```
input.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
```

You can chain as many event handlers as you want by adding further handlers in this fashion.

This can be done at any time after you create the control. To "unbind" the event you "subtract" it from the event :

```
input.KeyDown -= OnKeyDown;
```

Comment: Yes, but there is a ting, as you can see, the names are "unknown" so I can't just add a trigger to the `input`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _"the names are not known"_ - haven't you just assigned the Name (_"Name = "gtk_" + item.gtk"_)

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the value of the input name "gtk" + item.gtk" to store it correctly?

Comment: The _"sender"_ object parameter is a reference to your MaskedTextBox object - so you can cast that & access all properties of the class instance - I have edited the answer.